# rootViewController called without animations and other animations are not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In AppDelegate.swift I set the rootViewController using the following code, but there is a problem with the animations such as activityIndicator and progressView. I don't see activityIndicator at all, also progressView doesn't get updated in the view.

I did a debug and root View Controller's viewDidAppear(animated : Bool) is called with animated = false

ActivityIndicator Code

```
self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
self.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

//code to run while indicator is active

self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

progressView update code

```
progressView.setProgress(20.0, animated: true)
```

rootViewController set code

```
var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("downloadVC")
self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Is there any possibility that `progressView.setProgress` might be called outside of main thread?

Comment: I don't think so, getting warnings on the console while progressView code is running. `Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread.`